# Can't log in to github using PyCharm

Tags: github, pycharm

I'm attempting to log in to Github using the PyCharm IDE.

It keeps saying that I cannot log in with the credentials that I gave it. I made sure my login credentials were correct by logging in on the github.com site. I also made sure capos lock wasn't on. I swear I'm not crazy and am putting in the right credentials.

Any idea what the problem could be?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub has [shut down v1 and v2 APIs](https://github.com/blog/1160-github-api-v2-end-of-life) on June 12. PyCharm is still using v2 API, therefore it will no longer work until a new PyCharm version using v3 API is released. The same applies to the other products based on the IntelliJ IDEA platform (WebStorm, PhpStorm, IDEA, AppCode, RubyMine).

You can track the progress of [this issue in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85769).